# Pass Parameter for Lazy Instantiation

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, lazy-initialization

Given the following code snippet, how can I pass the member variable `_tenantContext` into the `Lazy<CloudBlobContainer>` constructor?

```
public class BlobStorage : IStorage
{
    private readonly ITenantContext _tenantContext;

    public BlobStorage(ITenantContext tenantContext)
    {
        _tenantContext = tenantContext;
    }

    private readonly Lazy<CloudBlobContainer> _blobcontainer = new Lazy<CloudBlobContainer>(() =>
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FileStorage"].ConnectionString;
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("attachments");
        blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

        return blobContainer;
    });
```

Comment: Can you please post what you've tried so far and why it is not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass parameters to constructor, when initializing a lazy instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414363/pass-parameters-to-constructor-when-initializing-a-lazy-instance)

Comment: I tried it that way, but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly object _bar;
    private readonly Lazy<int> _lazyInt; 

    public Foo(object bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
        _lazyInt = new Lazy<int>(() => GetLazyObject(_bar));
    }

    private static int GetLazyObject(object init)
    {
        return init.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```