# How do you instantiate a property on first access without using a backing field?

Tags: c#

I have an object property in a class that I do not want to create until the property is first accessed. I can achieve this with the following code:

```
private XObject _myObject;
public XObject MyObject
{
    get
    {
        if (_myObject == null)
            _myObject = new XObject(this);

        return _myObject;
    }
}
```

This in turn can be refactored to:

```
private XObject _myObject;
public XObject MyObject { get => _myObject ?? (_myObject = new XObject(this)); }
```

However is it possible to achieve the same result without using a backing field?

I can't use `Lazy<T>` as '`this`' is being passed as an argument.

Comment: Is [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/lazy-initialization) what you are looking for?

Comment: Is `public Object MyObject { get; } = new Object();` what you are looking for?

Comment: @aloisdg: probably not because it doesn't initialize the property on first access but earlier and even if this property is never used.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use Lazy<T> as I need to pass 'this' as an argument to the constructor - I will amend the question

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes indeed.

Comment: @J45: if you need to pass `this`, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414386/284240) answer your question?

Comment: @mjwills - question now updated

Comment: Would `public class Bob
    {
        public Bob()
        {
            _myObject = new Lazy<XObject>(() => new XObject(this));
        }
        private Lazy<XObject> _myObject;
        public XObject MyObject { get => _myObject.Value; }
    }` be acceptable (to be fair, it isn't much better than what you have now)?